# Docker: Issue with pulling from a private registry from another server

Tags: docker

I just started learning docker.

I have a private registry running on one server(server1), and can pull a test image from it on server1 by typing the following:

```
docker pull 127.0.0.1:5000/test
```

However, when I type the above command from another server, I get the error message below:

```
Error: Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connection refused
```

Am I missing something in configuration?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add command for what you typed in another server ? also give the result for `curl <docker registery server>:5000`

Comment: I reported this as issue https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/513 as well

Answer (score 0):

The IP 127.0.0.1 refers always to the local machine. So when you call 'docker pull 127.0.0.1:5000/test' from another machine, you must use the real IP of the server, not 127.0.0.1.

Maybe try to ping the Server first by calling `http://XXXXXXX:5000/v1/_ping` from the other machine to make sure it is available and you use the correct IP.

Comment: Thank you for the help, now I am using the real ip of the server but still having trouble to pull from the other machine..

Answer (score 0):

Docker 1.3 added '--insecure-registry' parameter which allows you to pull from a remote private registry. Refer this: [Setting up a remote private Docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026931/setting-up-a-remote-private-docker-registry/26800070#26800070)