# pull image from remote registry - docker

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have installed docker 1.11.2, I am trying to make one private registry for our office.

I followed this [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) to make private registry, I have successfully pull from localhost but I stuck trying to pull from remote machine.

**Short Description of what I have done**

**Step1 :**

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

**step2:**

```
[root@raj raj]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID                   CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              c54a2cc56cbb        11 days ago         1.848 kB
registry            2                   8ff6a4aae657        4 weeks ago         171.5 MB
```

**step3:** (for localhost)

```
[root@raj raj]# docker tag hello-world localhost:5000/hello-world

[root@raj raj]# docker push localhost:5000/hello-world
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/hello-world]
a02596fdd012: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4 size: 524
```

**step4:**

```
[root@raj raj]# docker pull localhost:5000/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from hello-world

Digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4
Status: Image is up to date for localhost:5000/hello-world:latest
```

It  is working fine

I am trying to pull the image from **private registry from remote machine** so I have altered the **step 3** like below

**step3:**

```
[root@raj raj]# docker tag hello-world 192.168.1.23:5000/hello-world

[root@raj raj]# docker push 192.168.1.23:5000/hello-world
The push refers to a repository [192.168.1.23:5000/hello-world]
Get https://192.168.1.23:5000/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record received with length 20527
```

but it throws error tls:oversized

I have some links related to this issue [link1](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026931/setting-up-a-remote-private-docker-registry/26800070#26800070) but it does not resolve my problem

I have some doubt about this link

1) I could not found any docker file in that location /etc/sysconfig/docker, /etc/default/docker for changing –insecure-registry

2) docker -d --insecure-registry 10.11.12.0:5000 (this command is not working it throws below error.

```
[root@raj raj]# docker -d --insecure-registry 192.168.1.23:5000
flag provided but not defined: -d
See 'docker –help'.
```

Please help to get pull request from remote machine to private registry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the sequence of docker command for making private registry

**Server Side**

```
docker daemon --insecure-registry server-ip:5000
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker tag hello-world server-ip:5000/hello-world
docker push server-ip:5000/hello-world
```

**Client side**

```
docker daemon --insecure-registry server-ip:5000
docker pull server-ip:5000/hello-world
```

Now you can pull/push from your remote repositories, for more detail of registry you can use this command `docker inspect registry` it will show where the images get store and more info.

Comment: `docker daemon --insecure-registry server-ip:5000` -not working, its saying 
`unknown flag: --insecure-registry` @bilal

Answer (score 2):

Update docker config to add  "--insecure-registry", usually the file is located in **/etc/default/docker**, if you use docker-machine the file is located in **/var/lib/boot2docker/profile**

Comment: in my case /var/lib/docker folder only present,  I followed installation from https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/fedora/    (install with dnf)

Comment: in that case, just do a simple search to find where the file is located "find / -name "docker" "

Comment: I tried this " find / -type f -name "docker" "  it list 1) /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker, 2)/usr/bin/docker second one size is 30mb, gedit get crash while open, it seems like shell script

Comment: if you know anyother way to solve this issue please mention

Comment: which version of os do you use ?

Comment: 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64 (fedora 22), I have posted answer please review this, take a look at my note part in that answer

Comment: try to find "docker.service" file

Comment: BTW, `-d` is not valid to start Docker daemon anymore.  It is `docker daemon`

Answer (score 0):

In the latest docker version you get `unknown flag: --insecure-registry` error, do the following:

Edit `deamon.json` file:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "server-ip:5000" ]
}
```

`deamon.json` file can found in the following path:

Windows: `%userprofile%\.docker\daemon.json`

Linux: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

> Restart docker after updating the `deamon.json` file

Then do the following:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker tag hello-world server-ip:5000/hello-world
docker push server-ip:5000/hello-world
```

Check the newly added image info

```
http://server-ip:5050/v2/_catalog
```