# start docker error when add --insecure-registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

i want create private registry and follow this answer [Setting up a remote private Docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026931/setting-up-a-remote-private-docker-registry)
 docker run -p 5000:5000 registry
and other servre modify  /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service file to disable https

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry 172.24.54.41:5000

i can curl 172.24.54.41:5000
sudo service docker stop
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl start docker
the error log in systemctl status docker.service

> docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2017-12-11 16:52:23 CST; 6min ago
>        Docs: https://docs.docker.com
>     Process: 13300 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry 172.24.54.41:5000 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 13300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
>   Dec 11 16:52:23 iZhp39y3a2bx21oz0waijyZ systemd[1]: docker.service failed.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue does not lie with your running of a registry but with your configuration of the docker service.

Could you link the content of your usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service  file?